# How to have an object's json inside inside another using Django Rest

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have 2 models:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    likers = models.ManyToManyField('User', blank=True, null=True, related_name='liked_posts')
```

Post model has a manytomany field to User model. I serialize them separately using rest like this:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Post model's json, displays the user object's id in 'likers': `'likers': 1`. Is there a way to send the user's json instead of it's id? Something like:

```
{
    'likers': [
        '1':
            'username': foo
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UserSerializer` for the `likers`:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likers = UserSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```